# Is series convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{n}$$
Is it convergent? Of course it's not absolutely convergent, but I'm not sure about conditional convergence. Leibnitz seems not to work here.

Comment: All that's needed for Leibnitz is the monotone decreasing $1/n$ and the bounded partial sums of the term $(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}.$

Comment: Yea, but partial sums of $(-1)^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ dont seem to be bounded, it's like -1 -1 +1 +1 - 1 - 1 + ..., how to show it's bounded?

Comment: The partial sums go $-1,-2,-1,0,-1,-2,-1,0$ etc and keep repeating. So they are bounded. PS Why did you delete the question a few minutes ago? Seems an OK question...

Comment: In the above by partial sums of the -1,-1 1,1 etc is meant to add the first 1 term, then add the first 2 terms, then add the first 3 terms, and so on.

Comment: @coffeemath Is it not Dirichlet's Test, not Leibniz's, that guarantees that if $a_n$ decreases monotonically to zero and the partial sums of $b_n$ are bounded uniformly, then the series $\sum a_nb_n$ converges.

Comment: @Dr.MV You are correct, I had misremembered the name. In fact Dirichlet implies Leibniz and seems more useful, applies to more series. For reference of anyone interested it is for example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, Dirichlet is quite powerful and subsumes Leibniz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\dfrac {n(n+1)}2&=\\
&n=4m+1&\rightarrow (4m+1)(2m+1)= odd\\
&n=4m+2&\rightarrow (2m+1)(4m+3)= odd\\
&n=4m+3&\rightarrow (4m+3)(2m+2)= even\\
&n=4m+0&\rightarrow 2m(4m+1)= even\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\therefore -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}{n}&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac1{4m+1}-\frac1{4m+3}+\frac1{4m+2}-\frac1{4m+4}\right)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{(4m+1)(4m+3)}+\frac{2}{(4m+2)(4m+4)}\right)\\
&<\frac23+\frac14+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{(4m)(4m)}+\frac{2}{(4m)(4m)}\right)
\\
&=\frac{11}{12}+\frac14\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{m^2}=\frac{11}{12}+\frac14\cdot\frac{\pi^2}6\\
\end{align}

---

Dr. MV also mentioned that, this series can be expressed in a closed form as $\frac{\pi}4+\frac12\cdot\log 2$.

Then it came to me that we could do this way too (although dividing it into two series may be arguable):

$$\left(\frac11-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\frac19\cdots\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac14+\frac16-\frac18+\frac1{10}\cdots\right)$$ $$=\frac{\pi}4+\frac12\left(\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15\cdots\right)=\frac{\pi}4+\frac12\cdot\log 2$$

Comment: The series can be evaluated in closed form.  This can be facilitated using the Digamma Function along with Gauss's Digamma Theorem.  The result is surprisingly simple and is $$\frac{ \pi}{ 4}+\frac12 \log(2)$$

Comment: @Dr.MV I see. Thanks. Now I see that it can be expressed as $\frac11-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\frac19\cdots=\frac{\pi}4$ plus $\frac12-\frac14+\frac16-\frac18+\frac1{10}\cdots$ $=\frac12(\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15\cdots)=\frac12\cdot\log 2$..

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be instructive to see that the series can be evaluated in closed form.  The development is facilitated using the series representation of the [Digamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula)

$$\psi(x)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+x}\right)$$

where $\gamma=\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n -log(n)\right)$ is the [Euler-Maschereoni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

We will also make use of [Gauss's Digamma Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Gauss.27s_digamma_theorem) to determine the values of $\psi\left(\frac{\ell}{4}\right)$ for $\ell =1,2,3$.

Now, starting with the expression developed by @KayK. we have

$$\begin{align}
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}}{n}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{4n+1}+\frac{1}{4n+2}-\frac{1}{4n+3}-\frac{1}{4n+4}\right)\\\\
&=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+1/4}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\\\
&+\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+1/2}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\\\
&-\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n+3/4}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac14\left(-\psi(1/4)-\psi(1/2)+\psi(3/4)+\psi(1)\right)\\\\
&=\frac14\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+3\log(2)+\gamma\right)\\\\
&+\frac14\left(2\log(2)+\gamma\right)\\\\
&+\frac14\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-3\log(2)-\gamma\right)\\\\
&+\frac14(-\gamma)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac12 \log(2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is very nice!